# Stripe test card for allowing non-captured but failing "real" captured charges

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a web-service that authenticates (capture=False) $1 during registration, and few seconds later I'm charging desired amount.

How to test the second part only?

Tried to use card from [Testing page of Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) (`4000 0000 0000 9995`), but even auth charge is declined. I want to allow auth charge, and decline only actual charge.

Comment: The card ending in `9995` tests for insufficient funds, rather than a failed capturing of authorized funds. Since authorization essentially reserves the funds for later capture, there isn't really a way to test a "failed" capture for a successful authorization. Stripe doesn't have a test card for this because any error in capturing would not be due to insufficient funds, but rather some other cause, which would be unrelated to the authorization (and thus unrelated to the card itself).

Comment: @taintedzodiac probably there is something that doesn't fail non-captured, but fails on `capture` call?

Comment: While a `capture` call could fail, the error you get would depend on the reason it failed. For example, you might attempt to capture more than is authorized, or the authorization may have expired, etc. That is something you'd mock in your own tests based on the error codes in https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes

Comment: @taintedzodiac but I actually do not use this authorization payment and capture there only $1 to filter bots and fake users. And create new charge for bigger amount few steps later.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking to test with a specific card, in that case. If you're not actually capturing, you'd want to instead use and test against https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/cancel which is how you cancel without capturing.

Comment: @taintedzodiac what I want to test: any non-captured - should pass, and fail only if I try to capture them.

Comment: That isn't something that Stripe provides a test card for, as it's not something that would happen in live mode unless there was some external reason that would generate a specific error outside of a failure to capture (like the authorization expired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of investigations, I did not found any appropriate solution that will allow to successfully create non-captured charge and will fail only on capture.

There are few options how to solve that:

- disable auth charge during testing and use [any test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) for that like
  `4000000000000341` (attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail)
- calculate full amount in advance as auth charge and capture full amount when needed